# Access form element from onsubmit handler with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have several forms on a page all with an onsubmit handler doSomthing(). How can I access the form element that actually called the handler? How to pass it to the function.

```
<script>
    function doSomthing( getThePassedElement ){

        // Do some changes in the form values

        return false;

    }
</script>


<form action="#" onsubmit="doSomthing( PassSomthingHere )">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#" onsubmit="doSomthing( PassSomthingHere )">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Change `PassSomethingHere` to `this`. Or better yet, get rid of the outdated `on*` event attributes and attach the event handler using unobtrusive JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I never have time to answer, you answer too quickly :(

Comment: @Alexis Don't worry it's a dupe anyway. That's why I didn't answer it :)

Comment: I have the same complain:P @RoryMcCrossan — Could you help me understand why I can not see `console` in my answer even after `preventDefault` ?

Comment: @Rayon it's because the form submission is blocked in the snippet iframe - see the console: `Blocked form submission to '#' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — But I have prevented it, it just prevents anything after form submission including `submit-handler` ?

Comment: You prevented the event continuing, but the event isn't even raised in the sandboxed iframe, so your handler is never executed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan —  Ooh! That is how it works.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just pass `this`, `this` will refer to current element which is `form`!

> `this` argument in `inline event-handler` refers to **`HTML DOM Object`** event belongs to!

```js
function doSomthing(getThePassedElement) {
  console.log(getThePassedElement);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return doSomthing(this);">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#" onsubmit="return doSomthing(this);">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**With `jQuery`:** Use `jQuery.on` handler for `submit` event!

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventdefault();
  console.log($(this).find('input.name').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Using `DOM-API`:**

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
[].forEach.call(forms, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this);
  })
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The most comprehensive & complete answer +1

Answer (score 1):

This is how you bind an event handler to `submit` using unobtrusive `javascript`

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        //Use $(this) to access the form
    });
});


<form action="#">
  <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#">
   <input type="text" class="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding simple id to each form will does the trick. try this code

```
    <script>
        function doSomthing( id ){
           var form = $('#'+id); // this is your form handle
           // Do some changes in the form values
           return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Html:

```
<form action="#" id="form1" onsubmit="doSomthing( 1 )">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="#" id="form2" onsubmit="doSomthing( 2 )">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: whats wrong with this answer, Why people are down voting to my answer??

Comment: You already have a reference to the element by using the `this` keyword so making a DOM request to get an element you already have is redundant. Also, this method relies on changing the id you provide in every instance which is brittle and requires maintaining if the HTML structure changes. If you pass `this` the code is always the same and there's no maintenance needed. The use of jQuery is also not needed. You were downvoted as this is about the worst way to solve the problem.

Comment: I understood that, people has already provided solutions on that scenario. Am trying to provide some more possibilities to the problem. That doesn't mean people down vote this. gross

Comment: It does, because it shows people that come to this question in the future that while this may work, it's a very bad method to follow.

Comment: but how come its helpfull people answering the same answer again n again. does that help anyone. plz answer

Comment: No - and I already closed this as a duplicate

Comment: JQuery: write less, do more.

Answer (score 0):

pass just 'this.form' to the called function.

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="doSomthing( this.form )">
    <input type="text" class="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```